# C# getting correct IntPtr pointing to already declared variable

Tags: c#, pinvoke, intptr

I am trying to write/read multibyte array directly to/from file, and was suggested using PInvoke WriteFile/ReadFile.

Basically my reading code looks like this now:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern unsafe int ReadFile(IntPtr handle, IntPtr bytes, uint numBytesToRead,
  IntPtr numBytesRead, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* overlapped);

..<cut>..

byte[,,] mb = new byte[1024,1024,1024];
fixed(byte * fb = mb)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\SHARED\TEMP", FileMode.Open);
    int bytesread = 0;
    ReadFile(fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), (IntPtr)fb, Convert.ToUInt32(mb.Length), new IntPtr(bytesread), null);
    fs.Close();
}
```

This code throws an AccessViolationException.
However, the following code does not:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern unsafe int ReadFile(IntPtr handle, IntPtr bytes, uint numBytesToRead,
  ref int numBytesRead, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* overlapped);

..<cut>..

byte[,,] mb = new byte[1024,1024,1024];
fixed(byte * fb = mb)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\SHARED\TEMP", FileMode.Open);
    int bytesread = 0;
    ReadFile(fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), (IntPtr)fb, Convert.ToUInt32(mb.Length), ref bytesread, null);
    fs.Close();
}
```

The difference is that I declare numBytesRead to be ref int rather than IntPtr.

However, everywhere where I find an answer to a question "how to get IntPtr to an int", it goes like:

```
int x = 0;
IntPtr ptrtox = new IntPtr(x)
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Why access violation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get an Access Violation is because new IntPtr(x) creates a pointer whose address is the contents of x.  so you have created a NULL pointer when x = 0.

The IntPtr constructor does not get the address of its argument.  It isn't equivalent to the & operator in C/C++.

You want to use the ref argument for bytes read; that is the proper way.  Furthermore, you always want to use a GCHandle to get the address of a managed object, so use it on your mb array, not fixed.  Just don't keep the handle for long, and don't forget to free it.

-reilly.

Comment: I am using IntPtr for bytes read because I want to read into multidimensional array. Any multidimensional array. That way, i can make a simple virtual wrapper for all cases, and I pass byte[,] or byte[,,] or whatever to the same function and it will work, because "fixed (byte* fixedByteArray = buffer)" doesnt care how many dimensions does buffer has. But if i declare ref byte[,] i cannot pass byte[,,] for example

Comment: You misunderstood me.  I do not advocate using ref byte[]; I advocate using ref int for the numBytesRead.  I tell you to get rid of the fixed on the array and use the GCHandle to pin it in memory during the read operation.

Comment: Why would he get rid of fixed? Fixed is better for localized use (as long as you can use an unsafe context). GCHandle is better for persistent use where a fixed block can't be used.

Comment: I advocate getting rid of "fixed" because unsafe code requires that the CLR only execute code from a fully trusted assembly.  This is a requirement that you may not want.

Comment: It's very interesting that IntPtr(<declared variable name>) works just fine in WIndows 10. But fails in Windows 7 for the reason described for same 64bit .Net versions. Weird inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

I think the access violation is because bytesread is managed, therefore the GC may move it, making the pointer you passed invalid.

Does the following work?

```
int bytesread = 0;
var pin = GCHandle.Alloc(bytesread, GCHandleType.Pinned)
ReadFile(fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), (IntPtr)fb, Convert.ToUInt32(mb.Length), pin.AddrOfPinnedObject(), null);
```

[edit]
I forgot the next line:

```
pin.Free();
```

[double edit]
Oh dear! I got the wrong end of the stick completely. What I'm saying applies more to handling managed data from the heap in safe code.

@plinth is exactly right, the code:

```
int x = 0;
IntPtr ptrtox = new IntPtr(x)
```

Creates a pointer with the value of x, not pointing to x. In your original code just pass:

```
new IntPtr(&bytesread)
```

or

```
(IntPtr)(&bytesread)
```

Comment: Semms to work. So, i must do this for everything i want to pass as IntPtr to the pinvoke method? Do I have to somehow release the "pin"? Can I pass GCHandle.Alloc(myVarName, GCHandleType.Pinned)AddrOfPinnedObject() directly to avoid extra line of code?

Comment: I'd stick with the ref declaration if I were you, the function is the same. But yes I forgot to say you need to unpin! So you cant pin, call, unpin in one line.

Comment: Okay, but generally, how do i make a pointer to something, without allocating it like this? Only via "fixed" keyword?

Comment: Sorry, yes fixed can be used to pin pointers as well, does the same thing as GCHandle.Alloc / Free I think. For local variables only, you can allocate memory yourself on the stack with stackalloc straight into a pointer, which is unmanaged so doesn't need pinned.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy.  See this little piece you're doing:

```
new IntPtr(bytesread)
```

That doesn't do what you think it does.  You think that it makes a new pointer that points to your variable bytesread.  It doesn't.  It makes a pointer that points to an address with the **value** of bytesread, which is 0.  The unmanaged code reads, then tries to write a number into the memory pointed to by the null pointer, which fails.

The other version works because the argument is declared as `ref int` which will make the marshaller pass an actual pointer to bytesread instead of the value.

Comment: Okay, so the correct way to make a pointer to bytesread is to use the "pin" construct proposed by Peter Wishart?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an unsafe context you can get a pointer to a blittable type, such as int, the same way you can in C or C++. In your case &bytesread. That said for simple pointer parameters you should always use the ref or out keywords.

Comment: Hmm. I try to pass &bytesread as a parameter to where it expects me to have IntPtr and it complains about being unable to cast int to IntPtr. Am I doing it wrong (I understand I should use ref and i will in end product, but I want to learn how to do this too)

Comment: When you use the address operator you get a pointer of the same type as the variable. In this case you have an int*, so you either change your declaration to take an int* or cast it to IntPtr (i.e. (IntPtr)&bytesread) or create new IntPtr(&bytesread).